# How to get specific text from text file using php?

Tags: php

I have a text file named Profile.txt which is in key:value pair form.

For ex:

```
  Name: ABC
  Father's Name: XYZ
  DOB: 11-11-2011
```

How do I access value ABC by key Name so I could store it in  database?

Here's the code:

```
  <?php
  $my_file = fopen('../img/uploads/ABC_1/Profile.txt' ,"r");
  $content = file_get_contents('../img/uploads/ABC_1/Profile.txt');
  echo $content;
  fclose($my_file);
  ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the content of the file into an array, then iterate through it and "explode" the lines with ":".

Like this way

```
$file = file('abc_1.txt');
foreach($file as $line) {
    /**
     * $keypair[0] => Name, Father's Name, DOB
     * $keypair[1] => ABC, XYZ, 11-11-2011
     */
    $keypair = explode(":", $line);

    /**
     * Switch for getting your favorite $keypair[0]
     */
    switch( trim($keypair[0]) )
    {
        case 'Name':
            echo trim($keypair[1]);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanx pal..but what if Name: ABC would be Name :ABC..that's not working.

Comment: @yash you need to `trim()` that.

Comment: Thnx @vivek_23 pal

Comment: Did update my solution with trim() on the keypair[0]

Answer (score 1):

Cany ou try this

```
$path = 'Yourpath to file';
$fileGet = file_get_contents($path);
$removedNewLine = explode(PHP_EOL,$fileGet);

foreach ($removedNewLine as $key => $string) 
{
    $ecpEach = explode(':',$string);
    $finalArray[$ecpEach[0]] = $ecpEach[1];

}

print_r($finalArray);
exit();
```

Comment: Yeah that worked too..Thank you for giving it time.I appreciate that